# Is "pour off" as a phrasal verb?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence? Is "pour off" a phrasal verb?

> Water poured off the roof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, "pour off" is not a phrasal verb.

According to this link (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/phrasal-verbs), a phrasal verb is a combination of a main verb and adverb/preposition that typically has a meaning that is not obvious from the meanings of the two words separately.

In the sentence "Water poured off the roof" **pour** indicates the action that is going on, while **off the roof** merely modifies it.

Pour has the same meaning in the sentence "Rain poured **from** the sky" or "Milk poured **into** the glass." Because the meaning is not dependent on the combination of verb+preposition, this is not a phrasal verb.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether it's a phrasal verb but [Oxford Dictionaries defines this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pour) very example as a *no object, verb with adverbial of direction.*

> (no object, with adverbial of direction) 
> **Flow rapidly in a steady stream.** 
>   *‘water poured off the roof’*